# Right button working as left button on Acer laptop touchpad

Tags: touchpad, 18.04

My new Acer Laptop just arrived (A315-51-5647) and after installing Ubuntu Budgie 18.04 I'm having problems with the touchpad. For some minutes it worked fine, but now when I left right click it acts as if I left clicked. Once in a while it works normally, but 99% of the time it's bugged. I didn't install any exotic package or made any suspicious configuration (on the touchpad I only switched from two finger to edge scrolling and turned off natural scrolling). With a USB mouse it works fine. I tried everything I could to no avail, please help and thanks already!

EDIT: Even if I switch the primary button to the right button both work as primary buttons.

When I xinput --list-props "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"

```
Device 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad':
    Device Enabled (143):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (145): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Tapping Enabled (298): 1
    libinput Tapping Enabled Default (299): 0
    libinput Tapping Drag Enabled (300):    1
    libinput Tapping Drag Enabled Default (301):    1
    libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled (302):   0
    libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled Default (303):   0
    libinput Tapping Button Mapping Enabled (304):  1, 0
    libinput Tapping Button Mapping Default (305):  1, 0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (280):   0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (281):   0
    libinput Disable While Typing Enabled (306):    1
    libinput Disable While Typing Enabled Default (307):    1
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (282):    1, 1, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (283):   0, 1, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (284):   1, 0, 0
    libinput Click Methods Available (308): 1, 1
    libinput Click Method Enabled (309):    0, 1
    libinput Click Method Enabled Default (310):    1, 0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (287):    0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (288):    0
    libinput Accel Speed (289): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Speed Default (290): 0.000000
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (294): 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (295): 0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (265): 1, 1
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (266):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (267):    0, 0
    Device Node (268):  "/dev/input/event7"
    Device Product ID (269):    2, 7
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (296):   <no items>
    libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (297):   1
```

EDIT 2: This command solved the problem

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad click-method areas
```

I found it here on AskUbuntu, but I lost the link. Anyways I hope it helped

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer instead of an edit if possible

Answer (score 0):

This command solved the problem

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad click-method areas
```

I found it here on AskUbuntu, but I lost the link. Anyways I hope it helped